# Multiple CircleCI builds in one repository

Tags: circleci

Using CircleCI, is it possible to trigger different builds (or different build behaviors) based on the path of a checkin in a single repository?

Say for example you had separate microservices in one repository, with their own tests particular tests, in different directories.

Can CircleCI trigger different builds for each microservice based on a checkin to a particular subdirectory that represented a microservice?

If that is possible, is it also possible, once a particular microservice is built and tested in isolation, to have same full system test suite run based on the successful build of any microservice?

Comment: How long do the tests take to run? Could you just run all tests on the same trigger? If they are unit tests, the run time should be nearly instantaneous, and if they are functional tests, you probably need to reduce the runtime if they are eating a lot of build minutes.

Comment: Whilst I am new to CircleCI and don't know the answer to the question, I would query first why you have several micro-services in the same repo. That's a warning flag for me - the whole point of micro-services is that they are separately developed, versioned and tested, to prevent the temptation of building "temporary" links between services that become ossified over time.

Comment: Good question on microservices in same repo -- if you do some research on this question, you will find that multiple voices with first hand experience (e.g. facebook, others) have moved micro-services to a monolithic repository because multiple creates too many silos for teams trying to work together.  I'm not totally convinced submodules might not be the answer.

Comment: Right, interesting. Do you have any links to articles about that experience to hand? I'd be interested to read about that (not least because I am juggling 11+ repos for one project atm!).

Comment: In answer to your first question, we expect to trigger much more than unit tests, and indeed the question comes down to running only the tests we need.  For example I could see some microservices triggering a performance test, and others not.

Comment: Google "microservices multiple repositories" and you will find several interesting articles.  Please let me know if you have good counter-arguments!

Comment: I [found this article](http://blog.shippable.com/our-journey-to-microservices-and-a-mono-repository), which seems to summarise the issue nicely. I'd not be keen to challenge someone who works at Shippable, since (a) they are probably very talented and know what they're talking about, and (b) they know their own story/velocity rate. However, I'm still not understanding why a "mono" repo produces a 5x improvement in productivity. 1/2

Comment: In the age of containerisation, surely "getting the whole stack to run on a laptop" should be a question of creating a repo containing DinD (Docker IN Docker) or server orchestration scripts to (a) install Docker Compose, (b) pull all images in appropriate tag combinations, (c) spin up all instances, (d) run functional tests for a happy path through the app. Or a shell script that clones out all repos on a dev machine, plus instructions on how to bring up the whole stack. 2/3

Comment: As for enforcing style across repos, that should be done automatically as part of the build process - a code sniffer stops a service build if it does not pass a scan. Next, getting all devs familiar with all parts of the stack is a manual process - even with a mono repo, devs can become too specialised in one area. Finally, sharing code across repos can be done using a package manager (I use PHP, so common code sits in a private repo and is pulled in via Composer). 3/3

Comment: When you use lots of repos then the effort to coordinate dependency versions and inter-dependencies become significant.  That would be my main reason, visibility, consistency and maintenance reduction.